# How to debug silent database errors (such as "save") in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, activerecord

How can I get further information on errors that occur silently in Rails, such as @object.save?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes AR silently fails for reasons other than validation errors.  A couple of other things to check are:

- AR callbacks that do not return true (eg before_save)
- Invalid parent/ child records
- @item.valid?, @item.errors.full_messages
- @item.changes, @item.changed?

I have also included user456584's comment on checking for validation errors.  And as Semyon said, @item.save! will at least raise an Exception even if it isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: +1 for filling in some other possibilites that no one else has mentioned here. This just saved my day.

Answer (score 10):

Add bang so that an error is raised when validation fails.

```
@article.save!
# ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Title can't be blank...
```

Always use this method in preference to `save` if you don't expect validation to fail.

Answer (score 9):

As per [this post](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/102720), something like the following works:

```
logger.debug @item.errors.full_messages
```